# private variables written to text file

Tags: python, private, instance-variables

I have listed the main function and defined functions below, however I am receiving the error that I do not have the attribute "output_info" to write the text file. When I try to use the following code it gives me the attribute_error. I am unable to copy the info to the required text file. I do not know how to call this private instance variable to the text file and why it is giving me the error that I do not have the attribute that has been defined. Please help!!

Defining Functions (Instance variables must be private):
    class Customer:

```
def __init__(self,email="",last="",first="",age=0,pswd="",card="",sec=""):
    self.__email=email
    self.__last=last
    self.__first=first
    self.__age=age
    self.__pswd=pswd
    self.__card=card
    self.__sec=sec

def input_age(self):
    correct=True
    while correct == True:
        try:
            input_age=int(input("Please enter age"))
            if input_age < 0:
                print("You have entered an invalid age, age cannot be negative")
            else:
                correct=False
                self.age=input_age
        except ValueError:
            print("You have entered an invalid age, age must be a positive whole number")


def input_password(self):

    import re
    correct=True
    while correct==True :
        try:
            password=input("Please enter a password 8-12 characters with at least one upper case letter, one lower case letter and one number")
            if re.search('[A-Z]',password) is None:
                print("Password must contain at least one capital letter")
            elif re.search('[0-9]',password) is None:
                print("Password must contain at least one number.")
            elif re.search('[a-z]',password) is None:
                print("Password must contain at least one lowercase letter.")
            elif len(password)<8:
                print("Password is too short, must contain at least 8 letters")
            elif len(password)>12:
                print("Password is too long, must contain at least 8 but no more than 12 charachters")
            else:
                self.pswd=password
                correct=False
        except ValueError:
            print("Please reenter password")

def input_card_number(self):
    import re
    correct=True
    while correct==True:
        try:
            card=input("Please enter your 16 digit card number")
            if card.isdigit() == True:
                if len(card) < 16:
                    print("Invalid card number, you may have missed a digit")
                elif len(card) > 16:
                    print("Invalid card number, you may have accidentally hit a number twice.")
                else:
                    self.card=card
                    correct=False
            else:
                print("Invalid card entry, no letters in card number")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid card number, try again")

def input_security_code(self):
    correct=True
    while correct == True:
        try:
            sec= input("Please enter the 3 digit security code")
            if sec.isdigit()==True:
                if len(sec) < 3:
                    print("Invalid Security Code, You may have missed a digit")
                elif len(sec) > 3:
                    print("Invalid Security Code, You may have accidentally hit a digit twice")
                else:
                    self.sec=sec
                    correct=False
            else:
                print("Inv
def getInfo(self):
    return self.first,self.last,self.age,self.email,self.pswd,self.card,self.sec

def output_info(self):
    self.getInfo()
    info=(self.first," ", self.last," ", str(self.age)," ", self.email," ",self.pswd," ",self.card, " ",self.sec,"\n")
    output_file = open('customers.txt', 'a')
    output_file.write(info)
    output_file.close()
```

Comment: `output_info` is a function, you need to call it with parenthesis

Comment: Python *doesn't have private variables* you are using double-underscore name-mangling, and you probably shouldn't be

Comment: Note, however, many professors taught Java for so many years, they end up teaching you Java in Python. That's fine, the fundamentals are the same, but realize, this is not the Python way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

Private variables do not change inside the class, so if you want to access them, you'll need to include the dunder ("__") prefix. For example:

```
class Customer:
    def __init__(self, email="", last="", first="", age=0, pswd="", card="",
                 sec=""):
        self.__email = email
        self.__last = last
        self.__first = first
        self.__age = age 
        self.__pswd = pswd
        self.__card = card
        self.__sec = sec 

    def output_info(self):
        output = " ".join((self.__first, self.__last, self.__age,
                           self.__email, self.__pswd, self.__card,
                           self.__sec))
        with open('customers.txt', 'a') as fhandle:
            fhandle.write(output)
```

Might I suggest you use an IDE that autofills the available attributes/methods for you until you get a feel for how they work.